# Report generation code using Jasper and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

This outputs the report in HTML. This fetches all records for an entity and then lists them in the report. Wondering if this can be made generic, right now it is only one entity and 2 fields. Also thinking what if PDF is asked along with HTML

```
@Service
public class DialogReportServiceImpl implements DialogReportService {
    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Autowired
    DialogueDBRepo myEntityRepository;

    @Override
    public String generateReport() throws Exception {

        
        List<DialogueEntity> dataList = myEntityRepository.findAll();

        Resource sampleReportTemplate = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:sampleReport.jrxml");
        InputStream reportTemplate = sampleReportTemplate.getInputStream();

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportTemplate);

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("param1", "Parameter Value 1");

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);

        HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
        ByteArrayOutputStream htmlStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(htmlStream));
        exporter.setConfiguration(new SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration());
        exporter.exportReport();

        return htmlStream.toString();

    }
}
```

The report xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              name="SampleReport"
              pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">

    <field name="subject" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="notes" class="java.lang.String"/>

    <title>
        <band height="50">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="50"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Sample Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>

    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30">

            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="200" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Subject]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="255" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Notes]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>

    <detail>
        <band height="30">

            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="200" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{subject}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="255" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{notes}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class DialogReportController {
    @Autowired
    private DialogReportService reportService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/generate", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String generateReport() throws Exception {
        return reportService.generateReport();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What do you mean by "_thinking what if PDF is asked along with HTML_"?